# Resetting a datagrid in ExtJs

Tags: extjs

I have a button with a working listener in an ExtJs Data Grid. I have a toolbar at the bottom with this reset button. I have no forms however. Hence, what is the code that will reset a data grid on click? I can workaround this by refreshing the page when clicking the button but its more smooth to reset it since there is no re-loading at all. Also, like this the settings chosen by the user will be kept.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reload the grid's store:

```
grid.getStore().reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

Hai Chris,
   Have a look at this it may help you [Resetting Datagrid in Extjs](http://www.extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=4392)